# Efficient low rank matrix-vector multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have large matrix, but with very low rank, say 2. Is there an efficient way to multiply this matrix by vector (to achieve linear complexity)?

Comment: Do you know the actual rank-2 expansion, or just know theoretically that it has rank-2?

Comment: For a matrix to be orthogonal, it must have full rank.

Comment: @augurar you right, I've mixed different questions.

Comment: @NickAlger just theoretically, isn't there an automatic/systematic way to find rank-2 expansion. Maybe looking at this expansion will help to find efficient way of multiplication.

Comment: There are ways, but then you have to factor in the cost of finding the top 2 singular vectors and singular values. The best modern ways for this are randomized SVD and the Arnoldi iteration, which require multiplying the matrix by several vectors - so you are back where you started. You could find a non-SVD low rank approximation with rank-revealing QR, but that's going to be at least as expensive as a matrix vector multiplication for a sparse matrix, and much more expensive for a full matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an [SVD representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of the matrix, you can use this to compute the product in linear time.  I'm not sure how to efficiently compute this representation, though.  You can also truncate the SVD of a higher-rank matrix to get a low-rank approximation.

More specifically, if an $m\times n$ matrix is of rank $r$, its (compact) SVD representation is the product of an $m\times r$ matrix, an $r \times r$ diagonal matrix, and an $r \times n$ matrix.  If $r$ is constant, you can multiply this by a vector in $O(m+n)$ time.

Comment: How can I compute product in linear time using SVD? I can multiply NxN matrix by Nx1 vector in O(N) only if it is diagonal/band matrix.

Comment: Or has any other structure with O(N) non-zero elements.

Comment: @DikobrAz I have updated my answer, hope this clarifies things.

Comment: I see, thank you for clarification.